# Exception ignored in message on program exit

Tags: python, windows, python-asyncio, python-3.6

I initially wanted to do async stream communication on windows.

```
from asyncio import *
from asyncio.subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT, DEVNULL
import sys

async def test(exe):
  inst = await create_subprocess_exec(exe, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
  inst.stdin.close()
  inst.wait()

# for subprocess' pipes on Windows
def initialize_async():
  if sys.platform == 'win32':
    set_event_loop(ProactorEventLoop())
  return get_event_loop()

loop = initialize_async()
loop.run_until_complete(test('attrib.exe'))
loop.close()
```

The above code generates the following.

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseSubprocessTransport.__del__ of <_WindowsSubprocessTransport closed pid=65088 running stdin=<_ProactorWritePipeTransport closed> stdout=<_ProactorReadPipeTransport closing fd=476 read=<_OverlappedFuture cancelled>>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 132, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 106, in close
    proto.pipe.close()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 84, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 573, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 357, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <object repr() failed>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 95, in __del__
    warnings.warn("unclosed transport %r" % self, ResourceWarning,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 54, in __repr__
    info.append('fd=%s' % self._sock.fileno())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\windows_utils.py", line 152, in fileno
    raise ValueError("I/O operatioon on closed pipe")
ValueError: I/O operatioon on closed pipe
```

How can I remove this error? stdin.close and wait seems not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that unlike in synchronous programming many `asyncio` functions are actually `coroutines` that should be awaited. See how `wait()` defined [in documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.asyncio.subprocess.Process.wait):

[image]

You should fix your code to await this coroutine:

```
async def test(exe):
  inst = await create_subprocess_exec(exe, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

  data = await inst.stdout.readline()  # readline, for example, is also coroutine.
  print(data)

  await inst.wait()
```

You won't see any error now.

Comment: I discovers that replacing with `create_subprocess_shell` on Linux, the exact exception is raised regardless of the presense of `await inst.wait()`. Not knowing why.

Comment: Facing the same issue on Mac OS while terminating a subprocess which has multiple tasks created even though I am using a combination of ```terminate()``` and ```wait()```.